# After deploy Apps show blank fields on tables and combo boxes

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-adf, weblogic-10.x

The following error happens sometimes in some apps:

I create/change an App in JDeveloper 11g, test it locally and everything works fine. Sometimes when I deploy the app to our Dev server (Weblogic 10.x) the app shows blank fields on tables and combo boxes. The weird part is that combo boxes have the right number of fields, they just are blank.
The DB is the same as when testing locally.
If the server is restarted it works fine.

The problem is every time this server has to be restarted everyone on the teams using it  have to be informed and given time to finish pending tasks, and every Q&A have to stop working.

Can someone help me or point me in the right direction. I am new to ADF and weblogic.

Answer (score 0):

Is there anything in the WLS log files when your application shows the empty data?
Are you using direct DB connection or a WebLogic Data Source?

Comment: I am using a data source, and log files have no unusual entries.